# Node CLI exits but debugger waits

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I have following lines of code:

```
var http=require('http');
var fs=require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req,res){

if(req.url==='/'){

     fs.createReadStream(__dirname +'/index.htm','utf8').pipe(res);

}

    if(req.url==='/somethingelse'){
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
   var obj={firstname:"xxx",lastname:"zzzz"}
   res.end(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

}).listen(1337,'127.0.0.1');
```

While I try to execute the same on node CLI, my CLI does not wait for request.It just quits, however the same piece of code works while debugging, i.e. It listens for request.Whats wrong with my CLI?Some settings or code?

Comment: Works for me. The REPL will allow you to keep running commands, but the server is running in the background. Also, __dirname is not defined in the REPL.

Comment: I did re installation of node.js and it worked.